# How to let make know about folders?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My directory structure looks like this,

```
source/
  |-Makefile
  |-a.c
  |-b.c
  |-c.c
include/
  |-arch1/
  |-arch2/
  |-common/
  |-arch1-c_files/
```

If `make a.i` is the command then it's straight forward to write `a.i` as target & `a.c`, corresponding headers with their paths as dependencies which would look like this,

```
a.i: a.c ../include/arch1/file.h ../include/arch2/file.h
     command
```

but it'll be long and tedious `Makefile`. I saw `%.i` shortcut. But how to write a generic dependency list that'd work for all the files in source directory?

and even, what to be written as target so that generated target would be placed in different directory and also won't get compiled every time? (Think of output object files)

Comment: Have a look at the [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) directive.

Comment: _But how to write a generic dependency list that'd work for all the files in source directory?_ We cannot answer this question without knowing what depends on what, which you do not explain. Apparently `foo.i` depends on `foo.c` but what about the header files? And if your project is a C project why do you have `*.i` targets? Shouldn't it be `*.o`?

Comment: @Renaud, am learning different targets